# R: split only when special regex condition doesn't match

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

How would you split at every `and/ERT` only when it is not succeded by "/V" **inside one word after** in:

```
text <- c("faulty and/ERT something/VBN and/ERT else/VHGB and/ERT as/VVFIN and/ERT not else/VHGB propositions one and/ERT two/CDF and/ERT three/ABC")

# my try - !doesn't work
> strsplit(text, "(?<=and/ERT)\\s(?!./V.)", perl=TRUE)
                                    ^^^^

# Exptected return
[[1]]    
[1] "faulty and/ERT something/VBN and/ERT else/VHGB and/ERT as/VVFIN and/ERT"
[2] "not else/VHGB propositions one and/ERT"
[3] "two/CDF and/ERT"            
[4] "three/ABC"
```

Comment: Do you want it to fail if it's directly after the possible match. ie: `and/ERT something/VBN` should fail, `and/ERT something something/VBN` should not fail ? quoting from @smerny.

Comment: Alex, your latest edit (str and return) still matches with my regex: http://regexr.com?369f3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you need to approach this in another way:

```
(?<=and/ERT)\\s(?!\\S+/V)
                  ^^^^
```

You will need to use `\\S+` because using `.*` will prevent a match even if `/V` is present two words ahead.

`\\S+` matches non spaces by the way.

Lastly, the final period can be safely ignored.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/bE4bK7)

Answer (score 4):

Actually you have made a tiny little mistake but it caused everything not to work:

```
(?<=and/ERT)\\s(?![^\\s/]+/V)
                  ^^^^^^^
            match one or more characters that are not white space or forward slash /
```

By the way, the dot `.` after the `/V` is not needed.

**Edit:** I have made some edits according to @smerny's comment and your edit.

Comment: This actually wont work if there is a `/V` something later on in the string: http://regexr.com?369ek

Comment: I mean it won't work because the `.*` will look all the way to the end of the string, if it finds a `/V` anywhere, it wont match. The OP seems to only want it to fail if it's directly after the possible match. ie: "and/ERT something/VBN" should fail, "and/ERT something something/VBN" should not fail.

Comment: The lazy quantifier wont do anything in this case, see what I mean in the comparison between [your current regex](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?369ek) and [my current regex](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?369eq) when there is a `/V` later on in the string.

Comment: @smerny Sorry I have misunderstood you at first, I will ask the OP to be make sure that is what he actually wants. Thank you.

Comment: Just to explain the lazy quantifier, it's in a negative lookahead so it's just looking ahead to see if `.*?/V` exists. If `.*/V` exists, `.*?/V` would also exist and vice-versa.

Comment: @Sniffer Thank you! Nice solution! :) I changed the case in order to have also the case that `/V` is after more then one word and a split is required. Also I deleted the point/s because it would confuse newcommers like me. Is it possible to delete the `.` in your post too? Thank you very much and a nice day!

Comment: @Sniffer Please ignore my last comment with the `.`. Because also others edited an answer discussing on the initial `.` issue. So I put it back! Thank you very much! And a nice day!

Comment: @alex So my initial solution was the right one, you wanted to split if the `/V` came after a few words ?

Comment: @Sniffer I want not to split only if `/V` occures in the next word after `and/ERT`. I added a case where `/V` occures in the second word and no split is needed. It works nice! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<=and/ERT)\\s(?![a-zA-Z]+/V)
```

The problem was that your `/V` preceeded and followed by one of anything and your example had more than one character between your space and your `/V`.

`[a-zA-Z]+/V` makes sure that the only thing between the space and the /V is a single word consisting of letters. I believe this is your requirement based on your description and examples given.

[**Demo**](http://regexr.com?369ee)

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you very much! Also for the important point in the comments with Sniffer. I didn't realised that point! BTW: I added a proper situation to the `text`. Wish you a nice day! :)

Comment: @alex, yes I saw you edited your post and I tested against that and it works as you expected as well. See [here](http://regexr.com?369f3) (I think this is what you were referring to)